# jquery problem with toggle event only fireing on the 2nd click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can anyone explain why the following jquery only fires the 2nd toggle event and how to fix it?  Specifically, every time I click the nested < a > element it brings up the alert "2nd click".

I tested the selector to make sure it was selecting the element properly and it does, or at least it inserted a class without any problems.

The selector is selecting the very last node in the unordered list that has an anchor tag.

```
$("#nav li:not(:has(li)) a").toggle(function() { //1st click
              alert("1st Click");
        }, function() { //2nd click
            alert("2nd Click");
        });
```

Nested HTML structure that fails:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
      <span>stuff</span>
      <a href="#">Cat 1</a>
        <ul>
           <li>
               <span>stuff</span>
               <a href="#">Subcat1</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li>
                       <span>Stuff</span>
                       <a href="#">Subcat Details</a>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, this works right and fires both click events:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
      <span>stuff</span>
      <a href="#">Cat 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://www.jsfiddle.net/RqwPr/

Comment: u serious?...crap...must have other problems

Comment: @Ronedog - You have any other event handlers attached to those `<a>` elements?

Comment: yep, there 4 other event handlers...I just removed all of them to get down to just this one and it fired right...i'll step through the other handlers and find out where the problem is.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ronedog - If you update the question with those, might be able to help find it quickly as well :)

Comment: Thanks nick...I had an extra ")" hanging out there ...works now.

Comment: @Ronedog - Glad you got it working...converting comments to an answer to close this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting to answer to close this out*

[The handler/code you have works ok in testing here,](http://jsfiddle.net/gwFbA/) it looks like you have other event handlers that are either erroring or blocking the click from occuring on those anchors.

Make sure to check that the other event handlers on those nested `<a>` elements are behaving correctly, seems the error is there.